# Objects in container

Tags: c++, object, containers

I'm creating a container class called "family", which keeps track of all people in a family, there are two requirement.

First, I should have a data element that keeps track of the number of objects in use.

Second, I should have a function that reports the valid elements in the array.

I'm not sure what's the difference between the two.

As I understand it, for the first requirement, I could create a counter and increase that counter every time I successfully load data into an array, right? If that's the case, then why do I need to have another function to keep track of the valid elements? Aren't they just the same?

Thanks.

Comment: What is a _valid element_?

Comment: Instead of creating a new container class, have you tried using an existing one like `std::vector` or `std::map`?

Comment: Why do you need to know if an object is in use?  Are you running in a multi-threaded or multi-tasking environment?

Comment: Sounds like, smells like, a good application for a *database*.

Comment: Is a person in a family not in use when they die?  I don't understand the need for the "in use" flag.  Search the internet for "mutex" and "semaphore".

Comment: What does *"report"* mean? Maybe you should ask your instructor for clarification.

Comment: Many databases can be set up to perform filters or checks on data before the data is updated or added.  In essence, telling the database the rules that make an element *valid*.

Answer (score 0):

A lot of issues can be resolved if you let a *database* handle your data.  Databases already include mechanisms for locking and some can be set up to track the number of writes and reads to a given record.

I highly recommend not developing your own container.  You not only have to spend time developing (writing your own container), but you need to spend time debugging it.  Databases and existing containers have already been debugged.

I recommend having at least two containers.  The first container has all the objects in it.  The other containers are indices of the form "key, pointer to record".  This makes searching for records faster and you don't need to change the order of the first container (a.k.a. no sorting).

The objects should contain your data and may want to contain other attributes, such as read counter, write counter and "locked".  You don't want two entities updating the same record at the same time or one delayed from the other.